# Mysql CAST return invalid data

Tags: mysql, cas, unsigned

I have a query

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(user_name as SIGNED)) as max_id FROM (`users`)
```

it returns

```
 2.01303045556E+12
```

but actually the maximum value is `2013030455555`

Anybody know how it happens??

Comment: But it is working fine [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4cea/4) you might need to format it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

`2.01303045556E+12` actually IS `2013030455555`.

`x E+12` means `x*10 ^ 12`

`2*10^12=2000000000000` (2 followed by 12 zeros).

This is expotential (usually floating point) number representation. See [Scientific notation at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) (scroll down to "E notation").

**To get rid of it** you may cast that data to decimal or integer, instead of float. Maybe there are better methods, but I dont know them.

Example:

```
-- example for 16 digits
SELECT MAX(CAST(user_name as DECIMAL(16,0)) as max_id FROM (`users`)
```

Another solution: change format of the number in SQL or maybe PHP if you are using it.

Comment: how to convert it into 2013030455555? if the number is too small it was return as actual value?

Comment: you should try use float, php does not support unsigned integers. (if you use php)

Comment: @Dennis he cant use float, because float "bigger" than 6 digits is displayed in expotential format in MySQL.

Comment: Now i getting the result,but i fail to find the next number of that number.  $row['max_id']+1 also getting in that format.How to convert 2.01303045556E+12 as 2013030455555 in PHP??

Comment: @shn You can use number_format function, link to help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php